# Mount host directories in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there any limit on number of host directories to be mapped in docker?  Also is there any option to mount everything in a directory and exclude few files?

[image]

Our application is build on one open source platform and our image extends the open source platform image. datanuclues.properties and bootstrap.properties are generated in config directory by that image and our configurations are generated as subfolders inside config directory. So I want to maintain all our app specific configs maintained in host instead of docker container.

Thanks for your clarification

Comment: Can you clarify your requirement to exclude specific files? Is it for security? Would making the files read only help, or if they appeared as empty files would that meet your requirement?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have just updated the question. Can you please check

Comment: @BMitch making the files read only will help? how to do that?